# Accidentally killed a Gnus group, how do I restore it?

Tags: gnus

I use Gnus for mail with `nnmail` backend. I was in Gnus [group buffer](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Group-Buffer.html#Group-Buffer) and accidentally pressed <kbd>C-k</kbd>, which called [`gnus-group-kill-group`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Subscription-Commands.html#index-S-k-_0028Group_0029). Did I just mindlessly deleted important mail? How do I restore my mail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Killing groups doesn't mean deleting them completely with all the mail, it means unsubscribing from a group and making it invisible. Read subsection [*Group levels*](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Group-Levels.html#Group-Levels) of Gnus manual to understand subscribedness to groups better. To restore killed groups first list them by <kbd>A k</kbd> ([`gnus-group-list-killed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Listing-Groups.html#index-A-k-_0028Group_0029)) or <kbd>L</kbd> ([`gnus-group-list-all-groups`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Listing-Groups.html#index-L-_0028Group_0029)), then subscribe back by <kbd>u</kbd> ([`gnus-group-unsubscribe-current-group`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Subscription-Commands.html#index-u-_0028Group_0029))

Comment: You can also yank it back with `C-y` if you did it recently.